# how can i return all element from my array with authorize === Administrator

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to return all elements matching authorize === Administrator or authorize === Visitor without success

hier ist what i have sofar.  [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FcFDG/)

```
var otherStuff = {};
courses = [
                { index: ['', 'overview'], moduleId: 'overview', title: 'overview', nav: 1 , authorize: ["sellers", "taxi"]},
                { index: 'rating', moduleId: 'rating', title: 'rating', nav: 3},
                { index: 'example', moduleId: 'example', title: 'example', nav: 5, authorize: ["Visitor", "Administrator"] },
                { index: 'apple', moduleId: 'apple', title: 'apple', nav: 6, authorize: ["User", "Administrator"] },

                ]

var resultSet = $.grep(courses, function (element, index) {
    // return all element with authorize === Administrator or authorize === Visitor;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(resultSet))
```

can anyone help me on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of my solutions prevent any variables from leaking into your closure and require no library. The self executing functions are so you can replace the literal array ["Administrator", "Visitor"] with any type of authorization.

The ECMA 5 one is also a good example of functional programming. The accepted answer DOES NOT WORK because it lacks the ability to test against multiple authtypes.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/FcFDG/3/

```
var acceptedTypes = ["Administrator", "Visitor"];

// ECMA 5

var resultSetA = (function(authTypes){
    return courses.filter(function(crs){
        return crs && crs.authorize 
        && crs.authorize.indexOf && authTypes.some(function(authType){
            return ~crs.authorize.indexOf(authType);
        });
    });
})(acceptedTypes);
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultSetA));

//Compatibility with all browsers (ECMAScript 3):

var resultSetB = (function(authTypes){
    var results = [], i, j, k, works;
    for(i=0; i<courses.length; i++){
        if(courses[i]&&courses[i].authorize&&courses[i].authorize.length){
            works = false;
            for(j=0; j<courses[i].authorize.length; j++){
                for(k=0; k<authTypes.length; k++){
                    works = works || courses[i].authorize[j] === authTypes[k];
                }
            }
            if(works)
                    results.push(courses[i]);
        }
    }
    return results;
})(acceptedTypes);
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultSetB));
```

Comment: somehow i have 2 element with example  see this please[{"index":"example","moduleId":"example","title":"example","nav":5,"authorize":["Visitor","Administrator"]},{"index":"example","moduleId":"example","title":"example","nav":5,"authorize":["Visitor","Administrator"]},{"index":"apple","moduleId":"apple","title":"apple","nav":6,"authorize":["User","Administrator"]}]

Comment: didn't see sparse data, one sec for ECMA3

Comment: Thought you wanted to doubles for dual-authorized users - my bad

Comment: the jsfiddle you just posted doesn't work and why are you using filter in // ECMA 5 filter 5 ist just for html for array you should use grep see the diff between filter and grep please

Comment: Filter is an Array.prototype member. Stack overflow is a learning platform so I thought I would should you how to do this with raw JS...
I also would like to point out the $.grep code is still wrong in the answer.
It's working when I run it and when I run it locally...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

This is a native function and NOT the $.filter call. The native Array.prototype.filter is much faster than the $.filter, and requires no libraries. I think you misunderstand, Array.prototype.filter !== $.filter... Note that there is not a single $ in my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48547/discussion-between-kougiland-and-enjoys-turtles)

Answer (score 1):

use [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to check whether the value exists in the array. [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) was not used because of [IE compatability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility)

```
var resultSet = $.grep(courses, function (element, index) {
    return $.inArray('Administrator', element.authorize) != -1
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ddsrK/)

---

But since you are using jQuery 2+, I assume you are not worried about ID < 9 then

```
var resultSet = $.grep(courses, function (element, index) {
    return element.authorize && element.authorize.indexOf('Administrator') != -1
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FRLPB/)